# Print Html output open in new window

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm trying to print a output of my Mysql records. What I need to print is based on the value of search input. How I can open it in new window using onclick function? Any help will appreciate.

**Index.php**

```
<input type="text" name="search" id="search"/>
<input type="submit" name="print" value="print" onclick="openWin(); return false;"/>

<script>
function openWin()
{
window.open("../print.php","name","width=900, height=1200,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes");
}
</script>
```

**Print.php**

```
if (isset($_POST['print'])) {
$search = $_POST['search'];
}
```

Comment: If you want to use `window.open()`, you can't use POST... at least not directly.   Consider using the query string instead, with `$_GET`.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the input in a form and open the popup on submit of form.

http://jsfiddle.net/wvkjfee2/3/

```
<form id="formID" action="../print.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="search" id="search"/>
    <input type="submit" name="print" value="print"/>
</form>

<script>
var myForm = document.getElementById('formID');
myForm.onsubmit = function() {
    var w = window.open('../print.php','Popup_Window','width=900, height=1200,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes');
    this.target = 'Popup_Window';
    return false;
};
</script>
```

Comment: What exactly happened? The popup does not open? I modified the code try change the about:blank for ../print.php

Comment: It's open a new tab not pop-up

Comment: It seems I had left parts of the code that I should have deleted, it is strange that in my test worked.